# Geometric reason for the intersections of two ideal to be radical

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Here $I_1= \langle xy,z\rangle$, and $I_2 = \langle z−y\rangle$ and $I_3=\langle z − x − y\rangle$ for $I_1,I_2,I_3\subseteq \Bbb Q[x,y,z]$.

A software tells me that $I_1\cap I_2$ is radical but $I_1\cup I_3$ is not. I was told that there is some geometric reason of this. Could someone please tell me why? Or in general, under what condition do we have the intersection of two ideals to be radical?

Thanks for any explaination.

**EDIT** I am sorry for the typo... The $I_1\cup I_3$ should be $I_1\cap I_3$. And the both of them are radical... The software is correct..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\sqrt{I} \cap \sqrt J = \sqrt{I \cap J}$, hence the intersection of two radical ideals is always again radical. Thus your software is not correct.

$I_1 + I_3 = \langle xy,z,z-x-y \rangle = \langle z,xy,x+y\rangle = \langle z,x^2,x+y\rangle$ is not radical, because the quotient is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q[x]/\langle x^2 \rangle$. Your software is wrong again. Geometrically the sum of those two ideals is not radical, because the line $x+y=0$ meets the coordinate axes (Given by $xy=0$) with order two.

Comment: Sorry there is a typo... I mean intersection of $I_1$ and $I_3$ is radical.

Comment: But now from the answer I see that why does the intersection is radical in sense of algebra... Thanks a lot. May I please ask what is the geometric meaning of the intersection of two ideals to be radical?(If it does have some geometric meaning).

Comment: The intersection of two radical ideals is always radical. However there is no particular geometric interpretation of this: Note that geometrically, intersection and product of two ideals are the same. And the product of two radical ideals is not necessarily radical anymore.